# Bounce processor account password

Tags: email, bounce

I'm running a CiviCRM on Drupal installation.
We currently seem to have some issues with the bounce processing and would like to make sure that GMail is working properly.
However, nobody seems to know the password for our GMail account anymore. The person who set it up is no longer with our organisation and the password reset attempts have been unsuccessful.

Is there some way to retrieve the password from within CiviCRM?
I did check, the password is not visible within the bounce setup.

I'm quite desperate, would like to avoid having to setup a new account....

Regards,
Tobbe

Comment: can you view password like "********" on the screen? in Civicrm Outbound option ?

Comment: Yes, that I can do